# calculating coordinate points with VB.net

Tags: vb.net, coordinate-systems

I am trying to build a coordinates system but am having trouble with how to..

What I have sofar is a textbox that allows the user to enter a length. This length is user defined but never smaller then 610 in length since this is the minimum unit size we use to build timber frames. The overall length of a timber frame is infinite (well not really, but it is for what I want) the timber frame has beams every 610mm set apart from each other (this is a legal requirement) so I want my vb.net to set coordinates for each beam at intervals of 610 then write that coordinates system to a text based *.SCR file

AutoCAD uses the script file to automate drawing procedures to draw a beam of 180mm x 50mmx 50mm

```
BOX…. This emplys the AutoCAD tool needed for uses
0,0,0…This emplys a starting or base point
180,50,50…this is the end point that completes the beam
```

As you can see the script is very basic lets say I want a frame and in my textbox I type 1260
I know that my beams would look like the following in the script

```
Box
0,0,0
180,50,50
Box
0,660,0
180,660,50
Box
0,710,0
180,760,50
Box
0,810,0
180,860,0
Box
0,910,0
180,960,50
Box
0,1110,0
180,1160,50
Box
0,1210,0
180,1260,50
```

I need to build a new reference point each time from building of the previous, all these coordinates need to be worked out in VB.net and then recorded to the text based *scr file

How can I achieve this? I was pointedout towards the direction of arrays but doubt that???

Answer (score 0):

the algorithm isn't clear.
see the increments at each step:
Box
0,0,0
180,50,50
Box
0,660,0             + 660
180,660,50          + 610
Box
0,710,0             + 50
180,760,50          + 100

Comment: Im not sure what you mean but to draw a single box in AutoCAD ussing acrip file I need to call the function which is "BOX" then for every inxtance of "BOX" I need to give a starting point which is pendable on the inface area i select within AutoCAD the origin in this case i have selected would be 0,0,0 ( i chose this because its a nice clear number but thtas not to say that the usser might indeed have selected 117.646, 224.252, 724,000 however ignore that im abble to get this figure within AutoCAD. The box now has a starting point and needs an endpoint wich in this XYZ axis environmet is 180

Comment: ,50, 50 then i have a gap before drwaing the next beam the coordinate system of autocad requiers me to mesure from the original 0,0,0 which given then the width of the previous beam and the 610 gap then comes to 50mm = 610mm = 660mm hope this explains better? ps reading it again i see that you are still addinmg the 610 no +610 i have allready worked that out in the algorithm